# What to say when you want to reach out to a professor

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use ‘Hello, XYZ this side’ in a formal conversation over text?

Answer (score 2):

In text messages, "Hello" is acceptable.  You can also use "Good morning" or "Good day".

You don't need to use *"**Dear** Professor"* in an email or text.

For a professor, it is always appreciated, and correct, to address them as "Professor", "Professor Smith".

> Capitalize titles, like doctor, professor, and judge, when they refer to **a specific person**. Don't capitalize those words when they refer only to an occupation.
>   *-- [Purdue writing lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/42/)* (emph. added)

The problem with the example is **"XYZ this side"**.  **There are no verbs.**

It would be better to say one of these:

> - Good morning Professor, this is Twinkle Jones.
> - Hello Professor, this is Twinkle Jones.
> - Good day Professor Smith, this is Twinkle Jones.
> - Good day Professor Smith, this is Twinkle Jones from your Economics 101 course.
> - Good day Professor Smith, this is Twinkle Jones from ECON 101.

***"XYZ this side"* or *"Twinkle Jones this side"* is not acceptable everywhere and is not standard English.**

Answer (score 0):

It is advised to start a formal telephonic conversation ( Either call or Message ) with the use of salutation.Hence

```
Good Morning Madam,XYZ this side.
```

will be formal instead of starting sentence will "Hello" .

Comment: Welcome, thanks for contributing!  "Good morning" is a very good suggestion, but "XYZ this side" is problematic and not globally understood.  I'll add more context in an answer.